# Getting the last 5 elements of a int and save the rest in another variable

Tags: c#, string, int

Having the following input:

```
int total = 41406511332;
```

I know I can get the last 5 elements of that `int` (`11332`) by using:

```
int lastFive = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToString(total).Substring(Convert.ToString(total).Length - 5));
```

But how can I get the rest of the items on another variable called `rest`?

This means, I want to get the following input:

```
int lastFive = 11332
int rest = 414065
```

**EDIT:** No worries about int overflow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't really need any string manipulations, just use mod division:

```
long total = 41406511332;
var lastFive = total % 100000;
var rest = total / 100000;
```

If you need to do that a lot, with different splits, you can move that to separate function:

```
static void SplitNumber(long number, int splitAt, out long firstHalf, out long secondHalf) {
    var divisor = (long) Math.Pow(10, splitAt);            
    firstHalf = number / divisor;
    secondHalf = number % divisor;
}
```

Use like this:

```
long total = 41406511332;
long first, second;
SplitNumber(total, 5, out first, out second);
```

Comment: You can even add `100000` as `const` or other field that you would not need to duplicate it.